# After i create a APK to PWA i see toolbar of browser

Tags: reactjs, android-studio, progressive-web-apps

I have a problem with my first PWA.
I have created one with reactjs and configured good manifest.
I follow step by step google guide.
PWA, works perfectly, and i see "add to home button".
After QA i wanted to publish it in store.
I used https://appmaker.xyz/pwa-to-apk.

Now i have app publish in the store but when i open it, i see a browser toolbar and i can't use it as a native app.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using TWA (Trusted Web Activity)?

[Using Trusted Web Activities](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa)

This can be achieved by proving that the app and the web trust each other.

If you can prove it, you can prevent the browser toolbar from being displayed.

I'm sorry if you don't get the answer you want.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was a path of digital assets. I solved it!

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I'm glad I solved it!

It seems that I forgot to reply.
Sorry for the late reply.